# Changing screen brightness in Android emulator

Tags: android

Can screen brightness changes be tested in the Android emulator?  I've tried various examples that all use the following code snippet:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = (*some float percentage*);
window.setAttributes(lp);
```

But I don't see any change in brightness in the emulator.  I've tested it in cupcake and 2.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Brightness changes do not get reflected in the emulator. To confirm, you can check the phone settings in the emulator (Settings > Display > Brightness) and changing the brightness from there. It will not change.

To see the effects of changing the brightness, you'll need an actual device running android.

Comment: Just an interesting (pre)historic observation, i guess: adjusting brightness worked for ARM emulators running Android 2.x images