# Changing backlight brightness in Appwidget is not responding instantly

Tags: android, android-appwidget, backlight, screen-brightness

I have created a simple Appwidget to control the brightness of the screen by this code:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                  android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 50);
```

When i click the widget, there is no change in the brightness of the backlight immediately.
But when i lock and unlock the phone, it works. I read [Changing screen brightness programmatically (as with the power widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget) that using dummy activity will give the solution. So i created an activity like this

```
public class Bright extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.finish();

}
}
```

In my AppWidget class i used intent like this:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Bright.class));
```

But when i click the widget, it force closes. Is my implementation is correct for my AppWidget??

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the brightness in your dummy `Activity` too by using `getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness` if you want it to respond immediately.

As for the crashing, you might want to post the stack trace. But first check that you added it to your manifest.

Comment: This is my manifest      <activity android:name="com.home.widget.Bright" ></activity>