# dim screen while user inactive in android 6.0(marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using the following code to dim screen on Android. 
It is working well for the android version except version 6.0 (Marshmallow).

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
params.screenBrightness = 0f;
getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

How to solve this problem for Android version 6.0?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266425/android-6-0-permission-denial-requires-permission-android-permission-write-sett

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/cant-get-write-settings-permission