# How to enable mobile hotspot programmatically in marshmallow and above android version?

Tags: android

I've tried to create wifi tethering Hotspot in Android Marshmallow using following code.

```
public class WifiAccessManager {

private static final String SSID = "mHotspot";
public static boolean setWifiApState(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    //config = Preconditions.checkNotNull(config);
    try {
        WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (enabled) {
            mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
        WifiConfiguration conf = getWifiApConfiguration();
        mWifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        return (Boolean) mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class).invoke(mWifiManager, conf, enabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public static WifiConfiguration getWifiApConfiguration() {
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID =  SSID;
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(Integer.parseInt("12345678"));
    return conf;
}
```

}

And also I have given all permission to access wifi in my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But it's not activating in marshmallow and above version.

Whenever I am enabling the hotspot I got this error

```
08-18 13:56:32.304 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-18 13:56:32.304 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-18 13:56:32.304 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at com.example.deneebo.ffconnect.WifiAccessManager.setWifiApState(WifiAccessManager.java:28)
08-18 13:56:32.304 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at com.example.deneebo.ffconnect.DeviceFoundActivity.onCreate(DeviceFoundActivity.java:72)
08-18 13:56:32.304 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6689)
08-18 13:56:32.304 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2709)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.deneebo.ffconnect was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.setWifiApEnabled(IWifiManager.java:1888)
08-18 13:56:32.305 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:     at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.setWifiApEnabled(WifiManager.java:1748)
08-18 13:56:32.306 27844-27844/com.example.deneebo.ffconnect W/System.err:  ... 15 more
```

Kindly help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i got the solution from the Google's developers website

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS

And I have added following permissions in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

and add the following lines in my code

```
>  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
>             if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {
>                 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" +
> getPackageName()));
>                 startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
> 
>             }
>         }
```

Thank you so much for your help Mr.lorenzo-s

Answer (score 0):

The issue, from the log, is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.deneebo.ffconnect was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```

Your app requires the `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` permission, and in Marshmallow this permission cannot be granted by simply declaring it in the manifest. This is a change they did to enforce security.

You have to ask your user to allow your app to use that permission explicitly. You can find more info in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35285034/995958)**.

---

*This reply has been edited after OP posted his logs*

Comment: When ever I am trying to enable hotspot, I got this error
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: @karthikeyanravichandiran Look further after that line, and search for the "Caused by" exception. You should post all the relevant log part in your original question.

Comment: @karthikeyanravichandiran I updated my answer after looking at your logs.

Comment: I have tried with the link that you have mentioned but still I got the same issue....