# IllegalArgument Exception while writing value on settings

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-settings

I am trying to write values using *putInt*. The settings I am trying to write into are  -

```
"android.settings.CAMERA_COVER_STATUS"

"android.settings.MIC_SWITCH_STATUS"
```

I am not sure if the above-mentioned settings are proper or not. But when I try to write values on them I get the following errors -

```
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot keep your settings in the secure settings.
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:651)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 INFO     logcat: LYNC PAL(6468): findClass java/net/Inet6Address loader 0x23c6
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1851)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:2275)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.371 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:2380)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.372 INFO     logcat: LYNC PAL(6468): findClass java/net/Inet4Address loader 0x23c6
2021-09-25 22:48:04.372 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:2374)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.372 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at 
2021-09-25 22:48:04.372 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.372 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2021-09-25 22:48:04.372 WARNING  logcat: System.err(4223):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Any kind of suggestion and help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266425/android-6-0-permission-denial-requires-permission-android-permission-write-sett/35285034#35285034 

This might answer your question

Comment: @MoonLight not actually. I am not quite sure if the properties are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Had to use the System Settings prefix to solve the issue. Added prefix "settings://system/" before the settings key. Now the keys become as following -

```
"settings://system/android.settings.CAMERA_COVER_STATUS"

"settings://system/android.settings.MIC_SWITCH_STATUS"
```

Also tested the values using the following code -

```
cameraStatus = Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),"android.settings.CAMERA_COVER_STATUS",1);
micStatus =Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),"android.settings.MIC_SWITCH_STATUS", 1);
```

They seems to be working fine.

Note: Added the answer myself so that if anyone faces similar issue, it might help.