# Android studio Dangerous permission

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions, user-permissions

I'm trying to change my system/phone brightness through my application. For this I need to ask for permission ("dangerous permission"). I'm not quiet sure if I've done the correct way but this doesn't seem work as it always returns permission denied.

```
public void switches() {
            if (systemBrightness) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS},
                        1);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Changed to system brightness: changing the “system brightness” is permanent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Changed to screen brightness: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {

                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

//Mani fest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />




  public void changeScreenBrightness(float brightness) {
        mBrightness = brightness;
        if (systemBrightness) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Settings.System.putInt(mContentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, (int) (mBrightness * 255)* preset);
            }
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = mWindow.getAttributes();
            mLayoutParams.screenBrightness = mBrightness * preset;
            mWindow.setAttributes(mLayoutParams);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No error visible so far..did you put `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission in manifest?

Comment: I've added my manifest permissions to the question

Comment: Really, noone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: your code doesn't seems to have any errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for dangerous permission is handled differently than vulnerable permissions. You need to use [`Settings.System.canWrite(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#canWrite(android.content.Context)) method to check if you can do that. And if not send appropriate `Intent` to the system by calling `startActivityForResult`:

```
public boolean checkWriteSettingsPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getContext())) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Everything written in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS)

Comment: I have edited my question with the intent permission. I'm now getting up a new intent/window that is titled "Aviability". But nowhere here will let me accept the  permission to let the app change system screen brightness

Comment: Is automatic brightness set? Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36001592/6507689

Comment: Yes ok but this is an outdated answer. As in since the API level of my application is 23 the permission declaration in manifest wont work?

Comment: My answer shows how to get `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission on API > 23. Linked answer shows show to check if automatic/manual screen brightness mode is set and how to set value.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just found what the problem was, a simple typo. Instead of asking for `ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS` I'm asking for `Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS)`