# Increase Screen Brightness is not Working

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I want to increase brightness, when user open my app. I got the code from following link :

[Changing screen brightness programmatically (as with the power widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget)

But it is not working. Is it require some permission? I had added WRITE_SETTINGS permission also. Still it not work.

So, anyone can help me? Is it possible to increase brightness from app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing screen brightness programmatically (as with the power widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget)

Comment: this should solve your problem. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically